# grunt-karma does not satisfy its sibling's peerDependencies

Tags: gruntjs, npm, karma-jasmine

I am currently running into the following issue:

```
npm ERR! peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.10.0 wants karma@~0.12.0
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.3.5 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-junit-reporter@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
npm ERR! peerinvalid Peer karma-spec-reporter@0.0.16 wants karma@>=0.9
```

From my understanding >=0.9 required by all other peers should satisfy the required ~0.12.0, is that correct? Or does semver count >=0.9 as >=0.9.0 < 0.10.0?